# How do I create a Docker file that runs a Caddy server and others on subdomains?

Tags: docker, self-hosting, caddy

I'd like to run the following services/docker images (on their respective subdomains).

```
╔═══════════╦═════════════════════╦═════════════════════════╗
║  Service  ║         URL         ║         Docker          ║
╠═══════════╬═════════════════════╬═════════════════════════╣
║ Plex      ║    plex.example.com ║ plexinc/pms-docker      ║
║ Calibre   ║ calibre.example.com ║ linuxserver/calibre-web ║
║ NextCloud ║   cloud.example.com ║ nextcloud               ║
║ Gitea     ║     git.example.com ║ gitea/gitea             ║
║ Caddy     ║         example.com ║ abiosoft/caddy          ║
╚═══════════╩═════════════════════╩═════════════════════════╝
```

**How can I do this?** I've got little experience with Docker, but understand its benefits as far as modularity and sandboxing. I've found [this](https://docs.docker.com/samples/library/nextcloud/), but that's specific to nginx and Nextcloud. I'd prefer to use Caddy because of its automatic HTTPS registration and HTTP/2 support.

Running on a path instead of a subdomain isn't preferred, but would be acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

I am not really experienced with Caddy per-se but it sounds like you want to have a proxy server set up. What you want to do is map Caddy ports (I'm assuming 80 and 443) to the host machine (https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#ports) and then in the Caddy configuration set up the necessary proxy forwarding.

For example to forward all requests to  plex.example.com you would just point the  plex.example.com domain to your server, in the server you would have your docker-compose (I am assuming) project running with 80 and 443 ports mapped to the Caddy service. Then when a request comes in your Caddy can forward the requests based on the domain name. So in this case you would check for incoming requests to  plex.example.com forward them to plex service (you can use the plex service name as hostname when using docker. In the network created by the docker-compose command the service names resolve to the corresponding IP addresses)

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description all of the services run on the same machine, but have different ports, like this:

```
╔═══════════╦═════════════════════╦═════════════════════════╦═════════════════╗
║  Service  ║         URL         ║         Docker          ║      Address    ║ 
╠═══════════╬═════════════════════╬═════════════════════════╬═════════════════╣
║ Plex      ║    plex.example.com ║ plexinc/pms-docker      ║ localhost:10001 ║
║ Calibre   ║ calibre.example.com ║ linuxserver/calibre-web ║ localhost:10002 ║
║ NextCloud ║   cloud.example.com ║ nextcloud               ║ localhost:10003 ║
║ Gitea     ║     git.example.com ║ gitea/gitea             ║ localhost:10004 ║
║ Caddy     ║         example.com ║ abiosoft/caddy          ║ localhost:10000 ║
╚═══════════╩═════════════════════╩═════════════════════════╩═════════════════╝
```

Then your `Caddyfile` could look like this:

```
example.com {
    proxy / localhost:10000 {
        transparent
    }
}

plex.example.com {
    proxy / localhost:10001 {
        transparent
    }
}

calibre.example.com {
    proxy / localhost:10002 {
        transparent
    }
}

cloud.example.com {
    proxy / localhost:10003 {
        transparent
    }
}

git.example.com {
    proxy / localhost:10004 {
        transparent
    }
}
```

If all your services run within Docker, you might also want to consider [Traefik](https://traefik.io).